Requring a Social Membership to a golf course
Imagine a developer who forms two companies. The companies are separate entities but they have the same CEO and the same owner. One builds homes for people in an over 55 community. The other runs a golf course. As part of the requirement for buying a home, he states that all home owners must maintain a social membership in the golf course. He also has that rule as part of the HOA for the 55 community.
After some time, he has all the  homes sold. Then every year, he triples the price of
the social membership in  the golf course. Since the owners of the home, must maintain
a membership in the golf course he will quickly get rich.
Would this be legal?

I know of a development with similar rules in my town, and the home prices there are adjusted for the significantly higher HOA (which includes the golf club membership). So the infinite price hikes are impossible since the homeowners would just end up with worthless properties and stop paying altogether.

And the home owners can change the HOA rules to remove the requirement.

@JoeW There might also be a good faith and fair dealing claim, but I like your thinking better.

I'm not sure the respective costs of running a golf course, building a subdivision, and a yearly golf club membership line up in a way that makes this make sense. Especially considering the higher fees will drive away members who don't have a HOA requirement, which must surely be the majority of the club.

@Cadence that's a good economic argument against the practice. Do you have a legal one?

I am thinking the only members of the club are those with HOA requirements.

FWIW, HOAs with mandatory golf club memberships (and often a minimum amount of spending on club meals as well) are common. My in-laws have belonged to them in FL, NV (two different ones), and CA. But, it is unusual for a golf club to be organized on a for-profit basis. Usually, they are organized as non-profits (although not 501(c)(3) public charities either, so no 26 U.S.C. § 170 charitable deduction). This removes the incentive to engage in the kind of behavior described, and the golf club board is usually elected by club members, which often overlaps heavily with the tied-in HOA membership.

In the U.S. there are about 5,000 for profit clubs (of all kinds, not just golf) and 8,000 non-profit clubs (again, not just golf clubs), mostly under 26 U.S.C. § 501(c)(7). But, for profit clubs are generally free standing, while tie-in to HOA clubs are almost always non-profit for the reasons suggested by the question (which prevents this issue from coming up). See https://privateclubmarketing.com/are-private-clubs-for-profit/  and https://www.bibliovault.org/BV.book.epl?ISBN=9780674001718

Third-line forcing
australia
The covenant that you describe (even without the price hikes) is a form of exclusive dealing, commonly called third-line forcing, that is prohibited by s47(6) of the Competition and Consumer Act 2010 (Cwth) (CCA) if it has the effect of substantially lessening competition in the market.
Third-line forcing occurs if one business conditions the supply of goods and services (e.g. a house) on the purchaser buying goods and services (e.g. a golf club membership) from another business. This is clearly happening here.
Substantial lessening of competition in the market is fact dependent and turns on what the effect of the conduct, the competition, and the market are. We'd need to know a lot more about the market for houses and golf clubs in the area to even begin to tackle this.
Notwithstanding, the vendor can approach the regulator, the Australian Competition and Consumer Commission (ACCC), for behavior that would otherwise be prohibited per se or, as here, prohibited if it substantially lessens competition. The ACCC will grant authorization if they determine there is no substantial lessening or if substantial lessening occurs but is offset by some public benefit. Acting while an authorization is in force is not infringing.
Unfair Contract Terms
The unfair contract term protections apply to consumer contracts, which include "the sale or grant of an interest in land to an individual who acquires it wholly or predominantly for personal, domestic or household use or consumption." It would certainly capture the sale of the house to an individual who intended to live in it or holiday in it; it may not capture a buyer who intended to rent it out.
A term that is unfair is void.

A term in a consumer contract is unfair if it:

would cause a significant imbalance in the parties' rights and obligations arising under the contract

it is not reasonably necessary to protect the legitimate interests of the party who would be advantaged by the term; and

would cause detriment (whether financial or otherwise) to a party if it were to be relied upon.



Courts have held that terms which unilaterally allow a party to vary the price without allowing the other party to terminate the contract in response, are unfair.

You have given me a nice long answer. However, it appears to apply only to Australia. I care about US law and Florida law.

@Bob: Note that official guidance is, "Even if you supply a jurisdiction tag, we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions."
